# Why array.push updates the view on ChangeDetection.onPush components angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have Race component on angular app that contains cars array.
All of my components using onPush change detection.

I have a button on race component that makes only cars.push(new Car) and all child components views updates according to this.

i don't understand why the view updates, it suppose to update only when reference changes.

(i made a check and i see that the reference is equal)

car component only display car.

someone can explain why is that happening ?

race component ts

```
import { Component, DoCheck, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exp-race',
  templateUrl: './exp-race.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exp-race.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ExpRaceComponent implements DoCheck {
  cars = [
    {id: 1, color: 'green'},
    {id: 2, color: 'blue'},
    {id: 3, color: 'black'}
  ]

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    console.log('RACE CHECK');
  }

  changeFirstCarColor() {
    this.cars[0].color = 'yellow';
  }

  addNewCar() {
    let x = this.cars;
    this.cars.push({
      id: 4,
      color: 'red'
    })

    console.log(this.cars === x)
  }
}
```

race component html -

```
<h1>RACE</h1>
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
  <app-exp-car [car]="car"></app-exp-car>
</div>

<button (click)="changeFirstCarColor()">Change First Car Color</button>
<button (click)="addNewCar()">Add New Car</button>
```

car components ts -

```
import { Component, Input, DoCheck, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exp-car',
  templateUrl: './exp-car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exp-car.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ExpCarComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() car;

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    console.log(`CAR ${this.car.id} CHACK`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the cause is a user action into this component itself. Angular know it can have changes. If your click have async calls (like http call), its result will not update the view.

Comment: i dont think i fully understand @Gilsdav

Comment: To understand how `onPush` strategy works, take a look at https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/ . You are interested by "OnPush change detection and event handlers" section

Comment: Ok i got my answer. ChangeDetection.OnPush triggered on multiple situations which one of them is event triggering from inside the component. so when i click the button inside the component CD is triggered. Thank you @Gilsdav